# Conga Composer 8 Repeat plain data

Tags: excel, conga, conga-composer

I need to repeat labels for rows while merging repeating data into excel. For example, I have the following template:
[image]

After merging I need it to look like:
[image]

Using the template above it looks like:
[image]

Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Given the way that [Repeating Dynamic Formulas](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Creating_Composer_Templates/Excel_Templates/Advanced_Excel_Templates/Dynamic_Formulas_in_Excel) work in Excel Templates in Conga, and assuming that the first row of Label 1/Value 1.1 is not all the way on top of the Excel spreadsheet, you can maybe try something like this:

```
&=&=IF(A{-1}="Label 1", "Label 2", IF(A{-1}="Label 2", "", IF(A{-1}="", "Label 1", "")))
```

*(replace the column A with whichever column you want labels to be displayed in)*